# alrm sound not works

Tags: iphone, alarm

I want to set alrms so i use this code.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotif.alertBody = @"Appointment";

    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

    //localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.soundName = @"Iphone_Alarm.mp3";
    //localNotif.soundName=@"sound.mp3";
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];
```

It shows alerts but not play the sound, sound name having correct case and spell.On device it also not having vibration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining full path to mp3 file:

```
localNotif.soundName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Iphone_Alarm" ofType:@"mp3"];
```

Not sure about the vibration though.

Comment: any kind of setting nedded for this on device. i can play the sound on simulator.

Comment: Just in case: is the volume turned on on your device?

Comment: It is open.,sound file size also matters.